# How to use css-in-js in ant-design components?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, jss, css-in-js

Actually, A ReactJS web application inherited to me and it was initialized by `CRA` and [Ant-Design](https://ant.design/). I just worked with Material-UI and had no experience with *And Design*.

The way Material-UI handles the styles is awesome but AntD uses `less` to handle CSS. it's very hard for me to work like ancients.

I searched a lot but didn't find a way to use `JSS`[**CSS in JS**] in a project with Ant Design.

I mean like below:

```
import { AntDCompo } from 'antd';
import { Styled , injectStyled } from 'react-jss';

const MyCompo = ({ classes }) => (
  <AntDCompo className={classes.container} />
);

const styles = Styled({
  container: {
    color: '#f00',
  },
});

export default injectStyled(styles)(MyCompo);
```

But in the Ant Design docs just declare like ancient stuffs:

```
import { AntDCompo } from 'antd';
import styles from 'myCompoStyles.less';

const MyCompo = () => (
  <AntDCompo className={styles.container} />
);
```

**How I can do it? or Is there any way to use JSS for AndD components?**

Answer (score 1):

As every CSS-in-JS, you can target the normal CSS-properties:

```
import { Icon } from 'antd';
const DarkHoverStyle = styled(Icon)`
  color: gray;
  :hover {
    color: palevioletred;
  }
`;
```

In some occasions you may need to target a specific `antd` **CSS class**.

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  .ant-tooltip-inner {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    color: black;
  }
`;
```

In the next example, we styled the hover color of an `Icon` and the default styling of the `Tooltip` component (changed the default black background):

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Tooltip title="Github Icon">
        <DarkHoverStyle type="github" style={{ fontSize: 100 }} />
      </Tooltip>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]